# TypeError: Cannot read property 'enableBluetooth' of null when using react-native-ble-manager

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am trying to use the react-native-ble-manager library to create a bluetooth app for android. However when I try to use BleManager in any way it returns a type error of "Cannot read property 'x' of null". I have added

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

To the android manifest file.
For react I tried

```js
import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';

export default function App() {
BleManager.enableBluetooth();
```

I have tried to get this git project to work, https://github.com/Vic-Orlands/Ble-Manager, however it returns the same error.

If anyone has a different way to create a simple bluetooth app for android, I'd love to hear that too.

Comment: Did you install react-native-ble-manager? Please note that [the library](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) itself offers an example, maybe you can try this one as well